# socketio.send() does not send data to client

Tags: python, flutter, socket.io

I am trying to send data from server to flutter app using socketIO. Although I am able to connect and emit, the server is not able to send data to client side.

Server side code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
from threading import Lock,Timer as tmr
from engineio.payload import Payload
import base64 
import io


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)
someList = ['apple', 'peas', 'juice','orange']
i=0

@socketio.on('connect')
def connect():
    print("a client connected")

@socketio.on('disconnect')
def disconnect():
    print('Client disconnected')

@socketio.on('msg')
def handlemsg(msg):
    print (msg)
    socketio.send("msg from server")
                

    
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "hii"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app,host= '0.0.0.0')
```

Client side (flutter)

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();


    IO.Socket socket = IO.io('http://x.x.x.x:5000', <String, dynamic>{
    'transports': ['websocket', 'polling']});

    socket.connect();


    socket.emit('msg', 'test');
    socket.onConnect((_) {
      print('connect');
      socket.emit('msg', 'testing');
    });
    
    socket.onDisconnect((_) => print('disconnect'));
    socket.on('*', (data) => print(data)); //nothing is printed

}
```

The result I get on the server-side:

> a client connected

> testing

However, I get no data on the client side. Where am I going wrong? Please help

Comment: do you you get error message when you run flask in console? Do you get any error messge when you run flutter?

Comment: in flutter you define `on('event',...` so in Python you may need `emit('event', someList[i])`. And the same for other - in futter you define `on('fromServer', ...)` so Python has to send `emit('fromServer', ...`. Eventually you my try in flutter `on('*', ...` to run code on any message from server.

Comment: you should also check `i` because after few requests it can be bigger then `len(someList)` and it may not send data. Maybe you should use `i = (i + 1) % len(someList)` to rotate list (at least for tests).

Comment: I can't run flutter so I tested flask using client created with [python-socketio](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client.html)

Comment: @furas I have removed the 'event' and 'fromServer' and I'm sending a message as a response to 'emit' from server-side, yet the problem persists :( (the flutter does not receive the message)

Comment: There are no errors :(

Comment: there is no error but `send()` probably sends it with different name than `msg` and flatter can't recognize it. Better use `emit(some_name, ...` and `on(some_name, ...`

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the 'emit(some_name, ...' and 'on(some_name, ...' Haven't I used it already ?

Comment: you used `send()` instead of `emit("msg")` and this `send()` can means `emit("message")` and later `on("msg")` can't catch it because it expects `"msg"`, not `"message"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test it with flutter but I tested it with client create with `python-socketio`

Main problem can be that `send()` sends message with name `"message"` like `emit("message", ...)` but your `on("msg", ...)` expects message with name `"msg"`, not `"message"`.

So you should use `emit("msg", ...)` in Python and `on("msg", ...)` in flutter.
Or you should use `send()` in Python and `on("message", ...)` in flutter.

---

Other problem can be that it may need some time to send message and receive it - and it may need extra time after connecting and extra time befor disconnecting - at least in my example I had to sleep to get results.

---

Full working code.

I added more `emit()` with different names.

**server.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'

socketio = SocketIO(app)

@socketio.on('connect')
def connect():
    print("client connected")

@socketio.on('disconnect')
def disconnect():
    print('client disconnected')

@socketio.on('question')
def handle_questio(msg):
    print('question msg:', msg)
    socketio.emit("answer", "msg from server")

@socketio.on('help')
def handle_help(msg):
    print('help msg:', msg)
    socketio.emit("support", "help from server")
    
@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "hii"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('start')
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0')
```

**client.py**

```
import socketio

sio = socketio.Client()

@sio.on('connect')
def connect():
    print('connected')

@sio.on('disconnect')
def disconnect():
    print('disconnected')

@sio.on('answer')
def answer(data):
    print('answer:', data)

@sio.on('support')
def support(data):
    print('support:', data)
    
# --- main ---

print('start')
sio.connect('http://localhost:5000')

print('sleep')
sio.sleep(1)

print('emit question')
sio.emit('question', {'foo': 'bar'})

print('emit help')
sio.emit('help', 'can you help me')

print('sleep')
sio.sleep(1)

sio.disconnect()
```

Comment: Good job. Good furas. Well done

Comment: @furas how can I continuously send data instead of only once?

Comment: I am unable to continuously emit from flutter side although the code is written within  void initState() {}

Comment: I don't know flutter but I expect it has some `timer` or `clock` or `scheduler` to execute some function periodically.

Comment: Isn't it an open connection to support real-time communication. The rest of the code within void initState() {} works continuously until the app is closed

Comment: as for me code inside `initState` should run only ince and you need some loop to repeate `emit()`